# h have aproblem when i tried to excute angular funtion from custom confirm-dialog component

Tags: angular

I created custom angular confirm dialog component which contains two buttons 
I send callback function for every button 
but I faced a problem because in dialog custom control can't read main component form control.

Custom Control service

```
   export class ConfirmDialogService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();  
    constructor() { }  
    confirmThis(message: string, siFn: () => void, noFn: () => void) {  
        this.setConfirmation(message, siFn, noFn);  
    }  
    setConfirmation(message: string, siFn: () => void, noFn: () => void) {  
        let that = this;  
        this.subject.next({  
            type: "confirm",  
            text: message,  
            siFn:  
                function () {  
                    that.subject.next(); //this will close the modal  
                    siFn();  
                },  
            noFn: function () {  
                that.subject.next();  
                noFn();  
            }  
        });  

    }   
    getMessage(): Observable<any> {  
        return this.subject.asObservable();  
    }  
}
```

my main component

```
showDialog() {  
    this.confirmDialogService.confirmThis("Are you sure to delete?", function () {  
      this.searchForm.get("SearchText").setValue(null); // error here can't read any form control
    }, function () {  
      alert("No clicked");  
    })  
  }
```

Comment: try to use arrow function inside showDialog `function () {` -> `() => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your function declarations to arrow functions:

```
    setConfirmation(message: string, siFn: () => void, noFn: () => void) {    
    this.subject.next({  
        type: "confirm",  
        text: message,  
        siFn:  
            () => {  
                this.subject.next(); //this will close the modal  
                siFn();  
            },  
        noFn: () => {  
            this.subject.next();  
            noFn();  
        }  
    });  

}
```

As you can see, I erased the:

```
let that = this;
```

because when we use arrow functions we are keeping the class scope in this case the "ConfirmDialogService".

[I recommend you read this.](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/)